# Dunder string method not being called on a objects in a collection

Tags: python

I am trying to add nodes to a list and then print the list. I have implemented a dunder string method that works when printing a single node by itself. However it does not work as expected when trying to print a list of nodes.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(3)

d = [a, b, c]
e = [[a], [b, c]]
print("a: {}\nd: {}\ne: {}".format(a, d, e))
```

This is the output

```
a: 1
d: [<__main__.Node object at 0x7f3d3bc11100>, <__main__.Node object at 
0x7f3d3bacb340>, <__main__.Node object at 0x7f3d3bb41a90>]
e: [[<__main__.Node object at 0x7f3d3bc11100>], [<__main__.Node object at 
0x7f3d3bacb340>, <__main__.Node object at 0x7f3d3bb41a90>]]
```

How can I get this to work as expected with not only lists, but any collection in general?

Comment: Python uses `__repr__` in this case, not `__str__`

Comment: Use `__repr__`, not `__str__`

Comment: `list.__str__()` calls `repr()` on the list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Chack this....

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)

a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(3)

d = [a, b, c]
e = [[a], [b, c]]
print("a: {}\nd: {}\ne: {}".format(a, d, e))
```